# Deleting Pictures- Will They Really Be Gone?

Tags: samsung

Lets say I were to delete a photo, is there any way possible this photo may be seen on this device ever again? Will anyone ever be able to see this deleted photo if they pull up my device on their computer or laptop? If I delete a photo am I going to have full reassurance that this photo will never be seen again?

Comment: It can be retrieved from the external SDcard using recovery tools.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of other points consider. Each of these cases provide a means to retrieve:

In [ES file explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en) app, there is a concept of recycle bin. If this is enabled, the deleted photo can be retrieved by visiting the recycle bin section. If the photo is not deleted by this app, this point will not apply.

The apps like [Google Photos](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.photos&hl=en), [OneDrive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.skydrive&hl=en) etc have an option to upload the photo to a cloud services. Deleting a photo **might** not delete in the cloud. If you do not have these apps installed or installaed, but configured to ignore the folder from which you deleted the photo, then the photo can't be found in the cloud.

And the last bit is if the photo is stored in an external storage, then it can be removed and mounted on a card reader in a computer and there are apps to recover. It is not assured recovery, but chances are there. If your device is rooted, there is an [android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fahrbot.apps.undelete&hl=en) to undelete the photo as well.